# Is there a way to turn on the camera's light with Python?

Tags: python, windows, camera, light

I have a project that is basically a loop of things doing things in a period. I need to know when are they working, so I was wondering if there's a way to turn on the camera's light as an easy way to 'notify' me. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using opencv.

```
import cv2
from time import sleep

while 1:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    _, frame = cap.read()
    print('doing things')
    sleep(5)
    cap.release()
```

It's basically reading the cam without opening it. For me it does not use a lot of CPU so, i think it's worth it. It does turn on the camera's light.